# Copy auto incremented value to other column during insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE object
(
    object_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    root_id int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(object_id)
)
```

The column `root_id` is a self referential foreign key.

Basically what I want is `root_id` to default to the same value as `object_id` when a new record is inserted, if `root_id` is NULL.

I thought a trigger would solve this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_default_original_id AFTER INSERT ON object
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.original_id IS NULL) THEN
        SET NEW.original_id = NEW.object_id;
    END IF;
END;
```

So when I run this:

```
INSERT INTO object(name) values('test')
```

I want both `object_id` and `original_id` to have the same auto-generated value

With trigger AFTER INSERT I get the

`Error Code: 1362. Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger`

With trigger BEFORE INSERT I run get the

`Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (...)`

I guess because `object_id` haven't gotten the generated value yet.

Of course I could just do this "manually" in my code after the insert, but I'm trying to do as few code managed statements as possible. Is there any way to easily achieve this during the insert statement?

Comment: please show all code: insert and trigger. In my opinion you need use sequence, not trigger

Answer (score 0):

You must use two statement:

```
INSERT INTO object(object_id, root_id, name) values(NULL, NULL, 'test')

UPDATE object set root_id = (select max(object_id) from object) 
where id = (select max(object_id) from object)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible solution although a bit quirk:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_default_original_id AFTER INSERT ON object
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
BEGIN
  SET NEW.root_id = (
    SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
      FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'XXX'
        AND TABLE_NAME = 'object');
END
```

Hope this helps.